# Laravel foreign key problems

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

How to relation foreigkey if its not a "id" ?

I Get an error:

```
1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:539
  PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:539
  PDO::prepare("alter table `player_items` add constraint `player_items_items_code_foreign` foreign key (`items_code`) references `` ()")
```

When i try this:

```
   Schema::create('player_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('player_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreign('item_code');
        $table->foreign('item_code')->references('code')->on('items');
        $table->integer('state');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Error is on this lines:

```
        $table->foreign('item_code');
        $table->foreign('item_code')->references('code')->on('items');
```

Its because i need to refer a relationship between those two tables but i can't use the id, i need to use de "code" into item's table:

```
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('minLevel');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Example of what item's code can be (is a string):

```
'code' => 'balde01',
```

It posible this relation ? Or i have to change the "code" to integers ?

Its just.. i don't wanna relation with the id, this is normal? or im just crazy?

Comment: I know this isn't a answer, but it might be worth looking into some database design. Ideally, player_items should link to an item via a column item_id rather than code.

Comment: And my recommendation is to not mix cases... Always use `snake_case` for database...

Answer (score 1):

The way you code it is wrong. Why do you have a 2 `$table->foreign('item_code')` ? As you can see at the error:

```
 PDO::prepare("alter table `player_items` add constraint `player_items_items_code_foreign` foreign key (`items_code`) references `` ()")
```

its not reaching the second `$table->foreign('item_code')` since the first one produce the error. It referencing nothing so it producing an error.You should change it to this.

```
$table->string('item_code');
$table->foreign('item_code')->references('code')->on('items');
```

The `$table->string('item_code')` is to create the table. and the `$table->foreign('item_code')` is add a constraints to it.

and make sure that the `items` table will be created before the `player_items` table.

in case the `player_items` table will be created before the `items` table you can always create another migration or just add the constraints after the `items` table :

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // tables
});

Schema::table('player_items' function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Assuming that there is a $table->string('item_code') has been already declare. If not you can just declare it here.
    $table->foreign('item_code')->references('code')->on('items');
});
```

Comment: Not working. I tried milion diferent ways but not working. If i reference "id" it works perfect, but if i try to reference "item_code" it full fails all time. any THANKYOU

Comment: I think im gona tell to myself: do not invent, always relate to the id, end of quote.

Comment: Well you can try to do something like `$table->string('code')->unique();`